# upgrade version using WIX

Tags: wix, installation, upgrade

I've made an installer using the WIX toolset (3.10). I'd like to enable upgrades but I can't make it work. Every time I run the msi it installs another version.
I can't figure out what's wrong. can anyone advise?

```
<Product Id="*"
       Name="$(var.PRODUCTNAME)"
       Language="1033"
       Version="$(var.PRODUCTVERSION)"
       Manufacturer="Manufacturer"
       UpgradeCode="UPGRADE_CODE"
       >
<Package InstallerVersion="200"
         Compressed="yes"
         InstallScope="perMachine" />

<MajorUpgrade Schedule="afterInstallInitialize"
              AllowDowngrades="no"
              AllowSameVersionUpgrades="no"
              DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
<MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AllowSameVersionUpgrades="yes" will probably fix this. When you test upgrades you need to either always update the version (one of the first 3 parts) between installers or just allow the same version upgrades.

from the [wix website](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/majorupgrade.html)

> When set to no (the default), installing a product with the same version and upgrade code (but different product code) is allowed and treated by MSI as two products. When set to yes, WiX sets the msidbUpgradeAttributesVersionMaxInclusive attribute, which tells MSI to treat a product with the same version as a major upgrade.

So your install thinks these two installs are separate things even though they share the same upgrade code which is why you get 2 copies in your add remove programs list.

Comment: This answer makes no sense to me, but maybe I'm the crazy one.  You are saying that by not changing the version, and not allowing same version upgrades, it thinks they are seperate things, even though it's identical but rebuilt?  If AllowSameVersionUpgrades="no", and the version doesn't change, the second install should error right?  Because it's the same version, which is not allowed...

Comment: If you use `<Product Id="*" .../>` as almost every tutorial and example do, then every build of the install you get a new product Id GUID generated which treats the two installs as different *things*. If you explicitly used the same product Id GUID the behaviour would be different and it would be treated like running the exact same MSI twice I think. But when you do that you need to change the Product Id GUID every time you also change the version which is tedious. If it is still  confusing, blame some developer back in the day thinking that doing it this way made sense :)

Comment: Haha.  Thanks for the clarification.  It is still confusing but I think I get the logic now.  FWIW (and for anyone else), I eventually realized MajorUpgrade is just some syntactic sugar over the previous (but NOT worse) <Upgrade ...> style.  I wanted to use the "newer" form at first but finaly switched to <Upgrade ...> and everything suddenly seemed to make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

I use a GUID for the `UpgradeCode` (I suppose that's what `UPGRADE_CODE` means).

You can also set the `REINSTALLMODE` property to change your reinstallation behavior.

It could look like this:

```
<SetProperty Id="REINSTALLMODE" Value="amus" After="FindRelatedProducts">Installed AND REMOVE&lt;&gt;"ALL"</SetProperty>
```

Just be aware that `a` will reinstall your product regardless of the installed version. But you can look up which characters you need for your installer.

For `Value="amus"` you can refer to the Microsoft documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371182(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it still doesn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: Ok what do you mean by "it installs another version"?
Do you have two different entries under "Programs and Features" or is the   version number changing or something like that?

Comment: two different entries in the "Programs and Features"

Answer (score 0):

In addition to your `MajorUpgrade` property it is crucial that your `UpgradeCode` does not change for future versions. Might that be the problem?